# Sum values in given Index order consecutively in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a list of index values that represent the order of the coordinates I should be visiting on a map. Each index represents (x,y).

```
Out[4]: [0, 8, 11, 6 ,10, 3, 4, 2, 14, 1, 7, 12, 13, 15, 5, 9]
```

Using these coordinates I generated a distance matrix. My aim is to find the total travel distance.

I manage to achieve it using `iloc` where I consecutively summed the index values. However need an automated way of doing this as I have a large amount of data to go through. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
In[6]: dmatrix.iloc[0][8]+dmatrix.iloc[8][11]+dmatrix.iloc[11][6]+dmatrix.iloc[6][10]+dmatrix.iloc[10][3]+dmatrix.iloc[3][4]+dmatrix.iloc[4][2]+dmatrix.iloc[2][14]+dmatrix.iloc[14][1]+dmatrix.iloc[1][7]+dmatrix.iloc[7][12]+dmatrix.iloc[12][13]+dmatrix.iloc[13][15]+dmatrix.iloc[15][5]+dmatrix.iloc[5][9]+dmatrix.iloc[9][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop and iterate through your list of indexes:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0, len(yourList)-1):
    sum += dmatrix.iloc[yourList[i]][yourList[i+1]]
```

Best

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the topic as answered ;)